# Basic styling of Localizable.strings in iOS

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, country, localizable.strings

From an Android background, I would have thought that it is possible to add a basic styling to iOS Localizable.strings by using HTML markup like over here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling

Is there any way to add some basic styling information? What would be the iOS way to display the following text in the given styling for many different languages:

**Title**

*Information1:* 
 blablabla

*Information2:* 
 blablabla

Do I have to add a new key for each word? That would be crazy if the structure changed based on the language... There has to be a way to do it like this for each country:

```
"text.screen1" = "<b>Title</b> <br><br> <i>Information1</i> ..."
```

Glad about any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to display HTML is to use a *UIWebView* and *loadHTMLString* method:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,200)];
[webView loadHTMLString:@"test <i>italic</i>" baseURL:nil];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

You can also use \n, but you can't change font/style of the rendered text of a UITextView.

Answer (score 1):

You could store your localized strings as Markdown formatted text, parse it with something like [GHMarkdownParser](https://github.com/OliverLetterer/GHMarkdownParser), and render it using an `UIWebView`.

Or you can just store plain HTML. I suggested Markdown because it would be easier to read.

You can also convert HTML to an `NSAttributedString` with a category of [DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText), or simply implement your own converter via `NSScanner`.